# Custom argument displayed as part of WPP tracing prefix

Tags: logging, trace, windows-wpp

I already have WPP tracing enabled with a couple of functions that have a hardcoded prefix like so:

`USEPREFIX(CUSTOM_LOG, "[Custom][%!FUNC!]");`

What I am trying to achieve now is to create another function that takes a custom argument which will be used in the prefix:

Function:

`FUNC PARAM_LOG{ LEVEL = TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION, FLAG = TRACE_ALL }(PARAM, MSG, ...);`

Prefix:

`USEPREFIX(PARAM_LOG, "[%!PARAM!][%!FUNC!]");`

According to this [OSR Community Question](https://community.osr.com/discussion/194399/custom-wpp-message-flags-displayed-as-part-of-tracing-prefix), that's possible but it requires a workaround which "hijacks" one of the predefined format strings. I tried implementing this with the `COMPNAME` format string by adding:

```
#define WPP_LEVEL_FLAG_COMPNAME_LOGGER(lvl, flags, compname) \
        WPP_LEVEL_LOGGER(flags)

#define WPP_LEVEL_FLAG_COMPNAME_ENABLED(lvl, flags, compname) \
        (WPP_LEVEL_ENABLED(flags) && WPP_CONTROL(WPP_BIT_ ## flags).Level >= lvl)
```

followed by

```
USEPREFIX(PARAM_LOG, "[%!COMPNAME!][%!FUNC!]");
FUNC PARAM_LOG{ LEVEL = TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION, FLAG = TRACE_ALL }(COMPANE, MSG, ...);
```

This doesn't cause any error but when I call the function:

```
char* module = "Module";
PARAM_LOG(module, "Message");
```

I get an empty module inside the .tmf file:

`"[][%!FUNC!]:%10!s!" //  LEVEL=TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION FLAG=TRACE_ALL COMPNAME=module FUNC=Log`

I am relatively new to WPP tracing so I am not entirely sure what's causing that issue...